# Relatorio gerado com reportview, diretamente em pdf

Tags: c#

Tenho um form, e nesse form, tenho um botão *imprimir* que abre um relatório do reportviwer feito com um dataset. O que preciso fazer com este relatório é  automatizar ele, em vez de eu clicar no botão imprimir, ele abrir a tela do reportviwer depois e ter que salvar em PDF pra depois abrir o pdf.

Gostaria de saber se e possível e se sim como fazer para encurtar este caminho todo e clicar no botão imprimir, e ele já abrir o relatório do reportview já em pdf, acionando o programa de pdf da maquina do usurário para visualizar, ou seja quando clicar no botão imprimir já visualizar em pdf.

Segue o código que esta no botão imprimir que chama o reportviwer.

```
public partial class frmPedioVenda : Form
    {

        public frmPedioVenda()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void frmPedioVenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void bntPesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PedidoVendaPHTableAdapter.Fill_ph(this.PedidoVendaDataSet1.PedidoVendaPH, txtPedido.Text);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

Aqui eu já crio o relatório e visualizo:

```
private void bntPesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PedidoVendaPHTableAdapter.Fill_ph(this.PedidoVendaDataSet1.PedidoVendaPH, txtPedido.Text);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou lhe ajudar com o código que uso para gerar o arquivo em PDF do `ReportViewer`

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;

byte[] bytes = this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
    "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
    out streamids, out warnings);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("output.pdf");
```

Comment: Pablo obrigado pela atenção este código que vc passou acima ele só gera não visualiza né.

Comment: Não, ele salva o pdf em disco e abre

Comment: Porque vc vincula o dataset 2 vezes?

Comment: Pois são dois DataSets diferentes, o `DemonstrativoDataSet` eu uso para montar o cabeçalho. e o `DemonstrativoProcedimentoDataSet` eu uso para mostrar os detalhes.

Comment: Mas dependendo de como está seu relatório, você não precisa colocar os datasets.

Comment: Então Pablo eu ja monto o relatório como mostrei no meu codigo acima, eu já vejo ele na tela montado, o que preciso e gerar direto em pdf e ja visualizar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68906/discussion-between-pablo-tondolo-de-vargas-and-junior-guerreiro).

Comment: Entra no chat..

Answer (score 0):

Sim, isso é possível. No método acionado pelo botão imprimir, crie um **DataTable**.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Após recuperar os dados e preencher o DataTable, carregue os dados no ReportViewer.

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("NOME_DATASET", dt));
ReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Por fim, retorne os dados, de modo que o **mimeType** seja do tipo **application/pdf**, conforme o código abaixo.

```
Warning[] warn = null;
string[] streamids = null;
string mimeType = "application/pdf";
string encoding = string.Empty;
string extension = string.Empty;
byte[] byteViewer = null;
string deviceInfo = null;

byteViewer = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("pdf", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warn);
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(byteViewer);
```

OBS.: Para utilizar a classe **Warning**, inclua o namespace ***Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms***.

Com este retorno, o arquivo PDF será automaticamente aberto no navegador do usuário.

Comment: Sério, seu exemplo usando o Response só irá funcionar se o projeto for web, no caso da pergunta é um projeto WinForms

Comment: Verdade não funciona porque e windows form e não web, estou com erros no Response

Comment: É verdade, não havia reparado nesse detalhe.