# Gerar PDF de Relatório .rdl com C# Windows Form ou ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, relatório

Tenho um relatório criado no Report Service e funcionando.

Como faço para gerar um pdf desse relatório com C# Windows Form ou até mesmo Asp.net?

Obs.: tenho que passar alguns parâmetros para o relatório, como por exemplo matricula e o ano do relatório.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/5846

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas é isso mesmo! Funcionou mas, ainda tenho uma dúvida. Quando o relatório espera parâmetros. Como faço para passar esses parâmetros por essa função? Quando peço apenas para visualizar no ReportView os parâmetros funcionam, mas quando chamo a função de gerar PDF gera erro. Criei mais uma pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269582/gerar-pdf-reportview