# Gerar PDF ReportView

Tags: c#, pdf

Peguei um exemplo (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/90835) para gerar PDF de um relatório. O Exemplo funcionou, mas tenho outros relatórios que precisam passar parâmetros, se eu colocar apenas pra visualizar no ReportView com os parâmetros funciona, mas quando adiciono a função de gerar PDF, gera erro dizendo que o parâmetro não foi passado.

Segue meu código:

```
            List<ReportParameter> listaParametro = new List<ReportParameter>();

        listaParametro.Add(new ReportParameter("Matricula", "351"));
        listaParametro.Add(new ReportParameter("Prefixo", "45072"));
        listaParametro.Add(new ReportParameter("SemanaIni", "201750"));

        reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(listaParametro);

 NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "senha");
        reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = myCred;

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;

        byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.ServerReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\paulo\\Desktop\\Teste_Gera_Relatorio.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("output.pdf");
```

Comment: Qual parâmetro ele acusa que não foi passado?

Comment: Consegui @PauloHDSousa, estava com algum erro no VS. Fechei e abri de novo e pegou os parâmetros normalmente com o código postado.